# $window.location.href refresh entire page when i use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: angularjs

I used html5mode in my application.
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

and when I use `$window.location.href` in my application it reloads the entire page.

If I remove `$window` and I use `$state.go` the page won't reload entirely like that.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there any solution to not reload the entire page when using `$window`?

Comment: try `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')` with `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 1):

The reload is indeed [due to $window.location.href use](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#what-does-it-not-do-).

You can use the [$location.path](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#getter-and-setter-methods) method to change the URL without reloading the entire page.

```
$location.path('/newUrlValue');
```

You can also add a base tag in your headers for relative links:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
</html>
```

For browsers which can't handle HTML5 History API, a hashbang prefix will automatically used (['!' by default](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration)) and can be changed using the `hashPrefix` provider's method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below:

```
// enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs)
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

And add:

```
<base href="/" />
```

to your `<head />`.